# gorm how to foreign self

Tags: go, go-gorm

for example:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    BestFriend User
}
```

I want BestFriend field foreign the same User model,How to define this with golang gorm package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see http://jinzhu.me/gorm/associations.html

```
type Profile struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Profile      Profile `gorm:"ForeignKey:ProfileRefer"` // use ProfileRefer as foreign key
    ProfileRefer int
}
```

or use another way

something like this ... did you try it ?

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserId int
    Username string
    BestFriend int
}

func GetUser(id int) User {
   //select * from users where UserId = id
}
```

Comment: I don't  understand your  approach. can you explain this more clearly?

Comment: You can't make recursive type... you will receive invalid recursive type User